# JS Fiddle - Bootstrap Popover Button Disappears on Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, jsfiddle

I created a **[JS Fidlde](http://jsfiddle.net/WayBehind/o27wqxz9/)** function so I can debug some popover external URL loading issues but now i'm even having issues with the `popover` button disappearing.

Is is only related to the JS Fiddle?

Comment: It has to do with you loading in a JS fiddle URL. Probably screws up the sandbox. Try loading any other kind of URL and your button won't disappear.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That being said, is there another way to load the external URL as the `load()` will only load same domain URL? Without the load I'm unable to debug the `popover` reloading issues.

Comment: You can use their [/echo/html](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) service to simulate loading in HTML from another site.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the reply. I think the `/echo/html/` only works with `Post` or am I missing something?

Comment: It is but [$.load uses POST](http://api.jquery.com/load/) if data is given, which you have to do to use `/echo/html`